# CMS with Word import or paste

Tags: content-management-system, ms-word

I am working on a project where we are taking a bunch of documents authored using MS Word and placing them online. Currently they are being published as PDF documents in order to maintain the formatting.

We are evaluating Content Management Systems (CMS), however, there is a bit of reluctance among the content publishers to use the CMS built in WYSYWIG editor. I can understand why, they are nowhere near as good as Word!

Some CMS have decent 'paste from Word' functions, but the one I have found that handles images as well is this [Wordpress pluging](http://www.nonprofitcms.org/2011/03/paste-from-word-to-wordpress-including-images/).

My question is - are there any Content Management Systems that have been built with Word integration in mind? Something that makes it as easy as possible to publish Word documents as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

So far from what I have seen, Microsoft Sharepoint had the best integration with the MS Office. I think most of them use Sharepoint as a intranet portal, but it could be also hosted as a public facing website. But compared to other CMS, it can be little pricey. But it has tons of features apart from content management.

[Sharepoint Demo](http://www.wssdemo.com/default.aspx)

[Public Facing Sharepoint Websites](http://www.topsharepoint.com/fortune-500-companies-using-sharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word does publish documents as HTML.

```
File > Save As > Web Page (Filtered)
```

[Office.com - Save a document as a webpage](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-a-document-as-a-webpage-HA102840141.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[ahmednuaman/gdrive-cms-php](https://github.com/ahmednuaman/gdrive-cms-php) uses Google Drive as a pseudo back-end to store and edit pages (Documents).

The self-hosted PHP and MySQL CMS requests text/HTML-exports of to display as web pages.

It also simplifies authentication and group permissions (if the editors are already Google/Drive users).